# Departure Date Greater Than Arrival Date

Tags: t-sql

How do I make sure my departure date is greater than the Arrival date in the following code.

```
SELECT ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, RAND(checksum(NEWID()))*1.5
* LengthOfStay.LengthofStay, ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
FROM Bookings, LengthOfStay
ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

Thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT 
          ArrivalDate, 
          DATEADD(day, RAND(checksum(NEWID()))*1.5   * LengthOfStay.LengthofStay, ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
      FROM   
          Bookings, LengthOfStay
    ) a
WHERE a.DepartureDate > a.ArrivalDate
ORDER BY a.ArrivalDate
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) takes an integer... and any decimal values returned from your randomization will just be truncated.  So you're likely just adding `0` to the `ArrivalDate`, resulting in the two dates being equal.

You could fix this by just adding a minimum of `1` to your randomization:

```
SELECT ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, 1 + RAND(checksum(NEWID()))*1.5
* LengthOfStay.LengthofStay, ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
FROM Bookings, LengthOfStay
ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

Comment: Would either of you know why the queries above would not insert into a table where the Departure Date is a Date field?